# Rotate a Slider

Tags: uislider

I have this code to rotate a horizontal slider:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
    sliderLine.transform = trans;
```

I can't get it to rotate. I'm assuming something along the lines of this in the .h file?:

```
UISlider *sliderLine;
```

or

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UISlider *sliderLine;
```

is needed in the header? Something like that?

Answer (score 2):

I took your code for horizontal slider and did something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    sliderLine.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(sliderLine.transform, 270.0/180*M_PI);
```

It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
slider.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(slider.transform , 270.0/180*M_PI);
```

try this.Above, slider is the slidername.